# Installing openCV with anaconda on ubuntu

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, anaconda

I'm trying to use the openCV library with anaconda (Python) , i am able to import the cv2 package but nothing has been able to access a .mp4 file so far. It's an issue with the ffmpeg thing which i have no idea about. I cannot post code right now since I'm using my phone. But if anyone can give me a Linux script or a tutorial that can help me work with openCV on python to be able to analyze mp4 videos with h264 encoding , that would be great

Answer (score 4):

I believe I am well on my way to a solution, so I'm posting this to help others along.

Download [conda-recipes](https://github.com/conda/conda-recipes). Sitting in that directory, run `conda build x264` and then `conda build ffmpeg`.

Because my system is 32-bit, I had to change one line each in `conda-recipes/x264/build.sh` and `conda-recipes/ffmpeg/build.sh` before I could run `conda build` successfully. I changed

```
export CFLAGS="-Wall -g -m64 -pipe -O2 -march=x86-64 -fPIC"
```

to

```
export CFLAGS="-Wall -g -m32 -pipe -O2 -march=x86-64 -fPIC"
```

I don't really understand what I'm doing, but I guessed that that would help, and now both builds run without errors.

However, opencv does not seem to be using FFmpeg; I still cannot open video files as I can outside of conda. I'll update if I ever get this working.

Comment: did you ever get further along?  I can use conda-recipes to build ffmpeg, but I don't think the built ffmpeg is being used by anaconda's cv2.  Please let me know, appreciate the help.

Comment: No, this is as far as I got before giving up. I was interested in OpenCV as a way to read video data into Python, and for that purpose I made [a video reader](https://github.com/soft-matter/pims) that simply calls FFmpeg from Python and pipes the output to a file. It's a temporary solution until I solve this OpenCV issue. I am still very interested in any progress you make.

Answer (score 1):

The default OpenCV package in conda does not have ffmpeg enabled. To solve this problem, I compiled OpenCV for Linux-64 with ffmpeg activated in CMake. I uploaded the package to my binstar channel, and you can install it using the following command:

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/jaimeivancervantes opencv
```

Comment: Tried this method on Ubuntu 16.04 but got an error when doing "import cv2": ImportError: libtiff.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory :(

Answer (score 1):

I think I just managed to build opencv3.1.0 for python 3.5 on LinuxMint17 (basically Ubuntu 14) using `menpo-opencv3` at https://github.com/menpo/conda-opencv3. This `menpo` package comes with `opencv-contrib` modules as well. Amazing...

First, make sure to `source deactivate` as building conda package needs to be done in the main conda env.

```
conda install conda-build
git clone https://github.com/menpo/conda-opencv3
cd conda-opencv3
conda config --add channels menpo
conda build conda/
conda install /PATH/TO/OPENCV3/PACKAGE.tar.gz
```

As the instructions says, in the default setting, FFMPEG is disabled. So, I had to edit `build.sh` file located in `conda-opencv3/conda` to make `-DWITH_FFMPEG=0` to `-DWITH_FFMPEG=1` before doing `conda build conda/`.

If `conda build conda/` is successful, you will see something like this at the end.

> If you want to upload this package to anaconda.org later, type:
>
> $ anaconda upload
>   /home/username/anaconda3/conda-bld/linux-64/opencv3-3.1.0-py35_0.tar.bz2

This is the path to the conda package we just built (I think).

So, now we can activate the conda env we want to install this package (ex. cv2-env)

`source activate cv2-env`

then

`conda install /home/username/anaconda3/conda-bld/linux-64/opencv3-3.1.0-py35_0.tar.bz2`

With this package installed, I could use `cv2.VideoCapture` to load some avi file I recorded in Windows 7.

(menpo even has opencv v2.4 https://github.com/menpo/conda-opencv as well but I had not tried. And note that 2 and 3 cannot co-exist.)

Comment: Got an error: fatal error hdf5.h:No such file or directory (ubuntu 16.04 64bit)

Answer (score 0):

```
+ curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Itseez/opencv_3rdparty/81a676001ca8075ada498583e4166079e5744668/ippicv/ippicv_linux_20151201.tgz -o /home/vasu/anaconda2/conda-bld/work/opencv-3.1.0/3rdparty/ippicv/downloads/linux-808b791a6eac9ed78d32a7666804320e/ippicv_linux_20151201.tgz
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--  0curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
 CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
 CApath: none
 Command failed: /bin/bash -x -e /home/vasu/anaconda2/conda-bld/work/opencv-3.1.0/conda_build.sh
```